# Service onDestroy Called even when there is still work left

Tags: android, android-service

I have a CountDownTimer that runs in a service when the app is in the background, onFinish(), the timer is supposed to check whether to start another timer or send a notification, the trouble is that once the timer is finished and the second timer is called, onDestroy is called at the same instant.

onStartCommand

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        startTimer()
        return START_STICKY

    }
```

startTimer

```
    private fun startTimer() {
        val context = this
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("startTimer: called with time left " + timeLeftInMillis / 1000)
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("startTimer: called timerType is " + timerType)

        // get values from datastore
        timer = object : CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished
                // Update notification text with remaining time
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Time remaining: ${millisUntilFinished / 1000} seconds")
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                timerState = TimerState.STOPPED
                if (timerType == TimerType.LONGBREAK || timerType == TimerType.SHORTBREAK) {
                    //save timer values to dataStore
                    scope.launch {
                        currentPom++
                        timerType = TimerType.FOCUS
                        timerState = TimerState.STOPPED
                        dataStoreManager.saveRunningParams(
                            timeLeftInMillis,
                            timerType.ordinal,
                            timerState.ordinal,
                            appVisibility.ordinal,
                            currentPom
                        )
                        //send notification
                        showTimerCompleteNotification(context)

                    }
                } else if (timerType == TimerType.FOCUS) {
                    //start next timer
                    nextTimer()
                    loadPomValues()
                    startTimer()

                }
            }
        }

        timer.start()
    }
```

log messages

```
2024-01-06 10:25:17.631 15069-15069 TimerService com.example.taskrabbit   D  TimerService nextTimer: Called
2024-01-06 10:25:17.632 15069-15069 TimerService com.example.taskrabbit   D  TimerService nextTimer: current timer type is SHORTBREAK
2024-01-06 10:25:17.632 15069-15069 TimerService com.example.taskrabbit   D  startTimer: called with time left 60
2024-01-06 10:25:17.633 15069-15069 TimerService com.example.taskrabbit   D  startTimer: called timerType is SHORTBREAK
2024-01-06 10:25:17.634 15069-15069 TimerService com.example.taskrabbit   D  onDestroy: called
2024-01-06 10:25:17.636 15069-15099 TimerService com.example.taskrabbit   D  onDestroy: Time left in millis is: 60
```

Comment: What prevents the server not to close immediately? It should close already after the first startTimer() call as far as i can see.

Comment: server==service